# A reverse question related to eigen value ?.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ be a real symmetric and positive definite matrix. Then for every $x\neq 0$, is there exists a constant $\lambda$ such $Ax=\lambda x$?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the transformation $(x,y) \to (10x+y,x+10y)$. Can you check that your statement does not hold for the matrix of this LT?

This is symmetric and it is  positive definite because $x(10x+y)+y(x+10y) \geq 9(x^{2}+y^{2}) >0$ whenever $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Not true.
$$
A=\pmatrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 2},
\quad
x=\pmatrix{1 \\ 1}
\quad
\implies
\quad
Ax=\pmatrix{1 \\ 2}
\ne
\lambda x
\quad
\text{for every $\lambda$}
$$